# Ember Store doesnot persists data across tabs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Suppose In Tab 1 - 
When I check in Ember Store - 
I have record {id : "1", firstname : "ABC" , lastname : "XYZ"}

In Tab 2 - 
When I check in Ember Store - 
I have record {id : "1", firstname : "ABC" , lastname : "XYZ"}

Now If I update record say lastname to KLM in tab1.
Then I m able to see lastname as XYZ in tab2

I am using the following strategy - 
1. Check data is present in store by store.peekALL
2. If data is not present then make store.query

Until I refresh tab2 I doesn't get the latest value.

Why doesn't store data persist across the tabs?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by Tab1 and Tab2, are they different instances your application? or are they internal tabs in your application?
Atleast from your question, I understood that you were not able to see the updated data. If that's correct, can you show me how you are updating the data to the ember store, so that I can have more details to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

> A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives
>   over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window
>   will cause a new session to be initiated. — Mozilla DOM Storage Guide

Therefore every new tab will be a new session.

**You can try**

https://github.com/jerel/ember-storage

This is a community plugin that synchronizes data between browser tabs using `localStorage`.

Comment: I want to make use of ember store. Your suggested plugin just save data in localstorage. I might have multiple collection and many records so it won't be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't store data persist across the tabs?

Browsers prevent this by default. Every browser tab is it's own little world, so to speak. Ember Data is just storing all of the data in RAM -- this is separate for each browser tab.

If you need to be able to synchronize data throughout every instance of your application, then you probably want to check out some means for your server to push new data to your clients (such as [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)). Aside from that, the suggestion to use `ember-storage` is a good one, since that's one of the few ways you can store data in one tab and retrieve it in another.